# How to expand SD Card disk size (clone smaller SD Card into Larger one)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, sd-card

I am trying to clone the content of my 16GB SD card onto a 64GB SD Card.

What I tried first was to just copy all the files from the 16 to the 64 manually. This did not work out, the tool using the card could not use the card anymore. So I did following:

1. Create `.dmg` file from 16GB SD Card.
2. Restore `.dmg` onto my 64GB SD Card.
3. Boot up the 64GB SD Card
   = works like a charm

BUT unfortunately it also "shrink" my 64GB card to 16...

Here is what I get typing `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *62.5 GB    disk3
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED                15.8 GB    disk3s1
```

So as you can see there is 62.5GB on the partition Card. How can I expand the 1: DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED to gain more space, like 60 or so?

Thank you!

€: I read somewhere that I can copy the image of the 16gb into the image of the 64 with `asr --source UNTITLED16.dmg --target n/UNTITLED64.dmg --erase` but that gives me `"n/UNTITLED64.dmg" is not a volume. Could not validate target - No such file or directory` :(

€€: As suggested by comments I tried copying things using `cp` and also `rsync`it did not help, it’s just the same result as manual copying of files.
Then I also tried `Disk Utility > Image > Resize` but unfortunately it did not work either, I get: `The selected disk image can not be resized. Operation not permitted.` Even if I add public read-write permission :(
Same thing using `sudo hdiutil resize -size 50G /path/to/image.dmg` gives me `hdiutil: resize: failed. Operation not permitted (1)`...

Comment: **_This failed._** What error message did you get? How many files are on this SD card? if there are many thousands or hundreds of thousands of files, (perhaps millions,) using the `cp /source /target` command bypasses the Finder when copying files. It is extremely fast, and with thousands and millions of files, it is one of the easiest methods. I'd first `cp` the files from the 16GB to the local HD on your Mac, then `cp` the files onto a newly partitioned 64GB SD from the HD. In Terminal, type `man cp` to find all the options. -R is needed to replicate and traverse directories, for example.

Comment: I'd use rsync over cp, since rsync is smarter and faster. Typically you'd use `rsync -a /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination`. Similar to cp, except that it'll keep more metadata, and is much faster when used a second time. Rsync can run circles around cp if you do a little research (type `man rsync`). It's pretty great :3

Comment: The card is used for Haxi on Wii U and the error I get is "-4". But that should not even be interesting for you because my question was how to expand the Size of an image/sd card.

So are you saying that this is impossible?
Copying the files from `.Spotlight-V100 > Store-V2`was for example impossible…
I’ll try the CP and RSYNC methods..

Comment: Ok using `rsync` for example when I want to copy the folder `.fseventsd` I get `skipping directory path/to/.fseventsd`. Using `cp` was very tedious but seemed ok. So I copied everything and tried it out but it still *failed* I get the same "-4" error as with copying manually. Haxi does not work anymore. It seems to look for more than just files... I don’t know why but apparently it needs an exact 1:1 copy. So please tell me how to enlarge the 16gb image, because that worked?

Comment: So back to the original question how to enlarge the image/space on the SD card? Thank you

Comment: Ok so in OSX there is this `Disk Utility > Image > Resize` but unfortunately it does not work, if I want to resize the image I get: `The selected disk image can not be resized. Operation not permitted.` Even if I add read-write rights to everyone :(

Answer (score 1):

Try booting from a [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) USB stick. You should be able to resize the FAT partition with that utility.